# Redux throwing error saying Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node':

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on my react application and getting this error

```
 Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

I am getting this in my redux action as per console.

This is are my actions and reducers

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    sidebarImageOption: 1,
    politicianList: null,
    selectedPoliticianRow: 1,

    movieActorList:null,
    selectedMovieActorRow:1
}

const FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST = 'FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST'
const fetchMovieActorList = (token, page)=> (dispatch)=> {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST});
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": url,
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            Authorization: token
        },
        success: function (response, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        },
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
        dispatch(fetchMovieActorSuccess(response.results))
        console.log(response.results)
    });
}

const FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST_SUCCESS'
const fetchMovieActorSuccess = (list)=> (dispatch) => {
    console.log('Received List: ', list)
    dispatch({type: FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: list});

}


export default function ImageReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_POLITICIAN_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, politicianList : action.payload};
            break;
        case SELECTED_POLITICIAN_ROW:
            return {...state, selectedPoliticianRow : action.payload};
            break;
        case FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, movieActorList : action.payload};
            break;
        case SELECTED_MOVIE_ACTOR_ROW:
            return {...state, selectedMovieActorRow : action.payload};
            break;

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I am calling action "fetchMovieActorList" in one of my react component, in componentWillMount method.

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMovieActorList("Token " + this.props.token_reducer.token, this.state.loadPage)
    }
```

Once the list is fetched I use it in render method to show content.

I am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch the result of fetchMovieActorList to the redux store, like this:

```
   componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(this.props.fetchMovieActorList("Token " + this.props.token_reducer.token, this.state.loadPage))
    }
```

You also need to integrate `redux-thunk` into your store creation process in `index.js`, e.g. like this:

```
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware( thunkMiddleware ) );
```

Then you can access `this.props.movieActorList` in your render function, and it will contain the results of the backend call as soon as they are available.

Also, the other action need not be asynchronous:

```
const fetchMovieActorSuccess = list => 
      ({type: FETCH_MOVIE_ACTOR_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: list});
```

Comment: The error comes only for the first time when the component is loaded. After that page loads properly because "politicianList" state is no longer the null after first load. If it works in second time then I think the actions are working fine. Any views here?

Comment: Is it coming because there is async task in action?

Comment: Please refer my answer to the question (posted by myself) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858799/failed-to-removechild-coming-in-react-while-dynamically-updating-an-array/49859426?noredirect=1#comment86734027_49859426This question can also be solved in the same way. It is a work around.